# Bootstrap elements work fine in locally hosted page on my computer, but when I host via Github none of my Bootstrap elements work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, github, github-pages, web-hosting, netlify

I have written code for a website on VS Code and pushed all my files to Github.

I then hosted the files for free on Netlify (not ready to commit to paid hosting as I'm just learning)

In the original code, I used Bootstrap 5 elements: btn and col-sm for responsiveness.

The btn element and the page responsiveness works absolutely fine when I view the page on my computer with live server.

BUT, when I view the Github html file with raw.githack.com OR when I visit the netlify.app site for the page, the bootstrap classes don't seem to come through at all.

I used npm to install Bootstrap in the project. In my index.html I use this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
```

I have checked in the github files and that is still linking to the right file.

I think maybe this method of linking Bootstrap just isn't working when I host online. Does anyone have experience with this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.